# javascript custom event losing value after adding a listener

Tags: javascript, custom-events

I'm creating a custom logout event, but after the event handler is assigned, the variable that holds the newly created event loses its value.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
  //
  // Prevent the creation and handler assignment of the login custom event
  // from happening more than once.
  //

  if( typeof( logoutCustomEvent ) === 'undefined' ) {

    // Create the custom logout event ...

    const logoutCustomEvent = new Event( 'logoutCustomEvent' );

    // At this point logoutCustomEvent has the right event object value.

    // Assign a listen handler function to the logout custom event ...

    window
    .addEventListener(
       'logoutCustomEvent',
       ( event ) => { if( event ) alert( 'logout custom event fired!' ); },
       false );

  } // End of if( typeof( logoutCustomEvent ) === 'undefined' ) ...

  // Test the logout custom event ...

  window.dispatchEvent( logoutCustomEvent ); // Dispatch the event.
</script>
```

When the `window.dispatchEvent( logoutCustomEvent )` statement at the end of the code block, above, executes, the following is displayed in the Chrome browser's console:

```
home:1334 Uncaught ReferenceError: logoutCustomEvent is not defined
at home:1334
```

However, if I set a breakpoint at the first line of the code shown above, and then monitor the value of the **logoutCustomEvent** constant, I can see that an event object is assigned by the `new` statement, but after the `addEventListener` statement, **logoutCustomEvent** value is 'not available' in the  browser's watch panel.

My code is based on the example shown on the [MDN .dispatchEvent page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent).

Why is this happening, and what do I need to do to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` and `let` define variables only in the current (and nested) code blocks. You cannot access them outside the code block they are declared.
There are 2 possible solutions:

#### 1. Use `var`

```js
if (typeof(logoutCustomEvent) === 'undefined') {
  var logoutCustomEvent = new Event('logoutCustomEvent');
  window.addEventListener(
    'logoutCustomEvent',
    (event) => {
      if (event) alert('logout custom event fired!');
    },
    false);
}
window.dispatchEvent(logoutCustomEvent);
```

#### 2. Declare `logoutCustomEvent` outside the if statement

```js
let logoutCustomEvent;
if (typeof(logoutCustomEvent) === 'undefined') {
  logoutCustomEvent = new Event('logoutCustomEvent');
  window.addEventListener(
    'logoutCustomEvent',
    (event) => {
      if (event) alert('logout custom event fired!');
    },
    false);
}
window.dispatchEvent(logoutCustomEvent);
```

Comment: Thank you very much drinking-code!   Your first suggestion was right on!  I now see that the event object still has its value when I dispatch the event.  I kept the event object's definition in side of the if test because I didn't want to override any other definitions  that might be elsewhere in my real code.  But if there weren't any, your suggestion on that detail would be right, too!

Comment: @Symfony-Wonderer Two things — 1) If drinking-code's answer solved the problem for you, you should _accept_ it as the answer. 2) Making `logoutCustomEvent` implicitly global by declaring it using `var` is probably the wrong way to go. Better to use `let` and declare it explicitly outside the loop.

Comment: Thank you Stephan P and, again, drinking-code.  Yes drinking-code did solve my issue.  As to being global, yes it has to be global, so that when I copy the dispatch event statement to where I really need it in my web-app, the variable containing the logout custom event is still in scope, which it is using the let statement, as you both point out, but as I said before, if the event already exists, then using let outside of the if-statement would redeclare that variable and override whatever was in it.